# How can I share 3rd party javascript libraries across multiple projects in a visual studio solution, without copying them into each project?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, projects-and-solutions

I am building a web project in Visual Studio that uses dojo, but I am unsure of how to link in the 3rd party dojo files so they get copied to the output directory.

In the past for things like jQuery, I placed the jquery.js file in a separate folder, went to "Add Existing Item," added jquery.js as a link, and set Visual Studio to copy it to the output directory (if newer).  This worked great.

For dojo, there are hundreds (if not thousands) of related external files.  This is not practical to add to Visual Studio ([though I did find a way to do it in bulk](http://greenicicleblog.com/2010/12/01/link-whole-directories-into-visual-studio-projects/)).

This makes me think that I am approaching this incorrectly.  How can or should I include something like dojo in a C# project without having to reference each file?  Should I use a post-build step to robocopy the files into the output directory?

My goal is to be able to build multiple projects which all use dojo, but I don't want to have multiple copies of dojo checked in, or have to reference each file in the project.

Answer (score 0):

Use the "Add as link" feature of Visual Studio.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9f4t9t92(v=vs.100).aspx

. . .

I am also a Dojo user.  You will want to learn to do Dojo builds, to reduce Dojo to just a few files, and host them on your server.  In many cases, in lieu of that, with some tiny loss of efficiency for the first load (after that, caching takes care of things) using the one of the CDNs like google to access the Dojo files is also effective.

Depending on your particular circumstances, it may be better to put the files out on a server, and just reference them in your HTML templates.  This is, for example, how we do all our internal Dojo applications in my organization--three developers use one set of Dojo files for all applications.

Comment: I'm already using add as a link (see my question).  This is unwieldy for a large number of files, even after doing it in bulk the project file gets modified to reference each file separately.  Making dojo smaller could help - but my question is not specific to dojo (I just happen to be using it in this case).

Comment: When I started writing my answer, that isn't what your question said, unless I am losing my mind :-) (That is entirely possible.)  However, I believe I have given you viable answers for several variants.  For one or two file, add as link is great.  For Dojo specifically, using build to get it down to a couple files is great, and also a huge performance boost on load.   For any web resource, just referencing a set of files already on the server is fantastic solution.  There are more ways, but for Dojo specifically, I think it is covered.

Comment: Personally, except for my professional stuff, where we have custom Dojo builds on our server (combining two of the suggestions here), I just use the copy on google CDN.  See https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide